# Traversing unclassified list items

Tags: delphi, tobjectlist

I have a list of many objects. Further, I have an additional group of lists consuming those objects. It's a strict rule that any given object either belong to the main list, or one of the other lists.

In general, the main object contains a master list of objects. Further, this main object also has its own concept of grouping these objects together into any separate arbitrary list.

I'd like to be able to query a list of those objects which are not currently a part of any of the other lists. I can naturally assume that I can synchronize a dedicated list of these objects, but that's not how I need to approach this. Instead, at any given time, I need to be able to fetch a list of those objects which are NOT a part of any of those group lists.

Another way put, out of that big giant list of all possible objects, I need to be able to iterate one by one through those which are NOT a part of any of the other group lists. Identifying whether it's a part of one of those lists is easy. But how do I fetch a list of items which are NOT a part of any group?

Specifically, without creating a whole separate list. I intend to use this main list of objects, yet filter out those objects which are a part of any given sub-list of objects.

More specifically, I need to be able to traverse through the list of objects which are not a part of any other list. I'd hate to keep track of a totally separate "ugrouped" list. I'd rather use the main list, and iterate each object in order in the list, while skipping over those objects which are part of the sub-lists.

For example, let's say I have a master list of 100 widgets. Only 30 of those have been categorized into some specific group list. The other 70 objects need to still be accessible by querying a list.

I'm looking for a loop something like...

```
for X := 0 to UngroupedObjectCount-1 do begin
  O:= UngroupedObjectByIndex[X];
  //TODO: Do something with O
end;
```

Comment: I think you gave the answer. Maintain an array of ungrouped member indexes.

Comment: I don't think this deserves the d/vote but it might benefit from a few more implementational details so we have a better idea of what you have in terms of lists and their type declarations: are you using generics, for example?  @LURD has a point with his comment, but another way of looking at it might be to have only a single list but in a class wrapper that provides custom accessors to sub-lists which implement the groupings you are after.

Comment: I would write an enumerator where the MoveNext skips all elements contained in the other lists. Obviously the enumerator needs access to all these lists.